# How can I change the startup form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to set `FORM2` as the startup form, but it is not available to choose, only `FORM1` is available. How can I change the startup form?

Comment: I suspect there's only a Main method inside `Form2` (you could change that), but its hard to tell without any actual code. Could you provide us more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your solution and find `Program.cs` file and then change it as:

```
Application.Run(new Form2());
```

Comment: Hello
I thank you for the answer
I did as you said
and he "worked"
in the sense now it appears to me for a few seconds
the desired form
but then it closes by itself :(

Comment: Can you share your code? (maybe Program.cs file content can help to get more information about your problem)

Comment: hello thank you so much
it was already solved by following your instructions!
only that the function was activated
application.exit () in a timer
I do not know how!
everything works now.
thank you so much.
:)

Answer (score 3):

Go to program.cs and change the code as folling

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AttendanceRecorder
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

           Application.Run(new Form2());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your program class, below code would have been written.

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

change it to

```
Application.Run(new Form2());
```